# Find the application from which TD query submitted

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I am using Teradata v14. I want to use the `PDCRINFO.DBQL*` history tables to find out the application from which a particular query was submitted by a user.

For instance, I would like to know if a query was submitted from SQL Asst or by Business Objects, or by Informatica or may be even by a bteq script from unix etc.

Can anyone please advise ? Any pointers appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In DBQL you have the AppID. This one is provided by the Application itself and sadly not always that self-explaining. But you can identify the App.

Mostly you have to group some AppIDs to one App when doing reporting. E.g

```
    WHEN DBQL.AppID LIKE ANY ('QUERYMAN', 'SQLA%') THEN 'TD SQL Assistant'
   ,WHEN DBQL.AppID LIKE ANY ('BUSOBJ', 'WEBIRICHCLIENT', 'WIREPORTSERVER') THEN 'SAP BusinessObjects'
```